# npgsql timeout during reading attempt

Tags: c#, postgresql, timeout, npgsql

I have a C# function to do a bulk insert in postgresql. What basically is happening here is that i have an array of generic entities, which will be turned into a DataTable, which is then used with a BinaryImport to insert the data into my postgres database. After the bulk insert i read the inserted data back from the database and populate the entities with this data (i use a temporary column do ascertain if a row of the table has been inserted with the last bulk insert).

This worked fine until i have tried to do a bulk insert with approximately 1.000.000 (978.767) rows. (Before i have only used ~ 500.000 rows)

After ~ 4 minutes I get the following Exception:

> Npgsql.NpgsqlException: Exception while reading from stream ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during reading attempt

The exception occurs on the line `while(reader.Read())` of the part where i read back the inserted data.

Here is my code:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> InsertBulkReader<TEntity>(TEntity[] entities)
{
    var table = ClientEntity.GetTable<TEntity>();
    var nonIdColumns = table.Columns.Where(column => !column.IsIdentity);
    var timeStampColumn = new Column() { Name = "TMP_BULK_INSERT_TIME_STAMP", PgType = NpgsqlDbType.TimestampTz };
    //Adding timeStampColumn to the actual table

    using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(base.ConnectionString))
    {

        connection.Open();

        using (var transactionScope = TransactionScopeUtil.Create(Transaction.Current))
        {
            var cmd = $"COPY {table.FullName()} ({string.Join(",", nonIdColumns.Concat(new List<Column>() { timeStampColumn }).Select(column => column.Name))}) FROM STDIN BINARY";

            using (var writer = connection.BeginBinaryImport(cmd))
            {
                writer.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

                foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    writer.StartRow();
                    foreach (var column in nonIdColumns)
                    {
                        if (column.PgType == NpgsqlDbType.Unknown || column.PgType == (NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Unknown))
                        {
                            writer.Write(row[column.Name]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            writer.Write(row[column.Name], column.PgType);
                        }
                    }
                    writer.Write(row[timeStampColumn.Name], timeStampColumn.PgType);
                }
                writer.Complete();
                writer.Close();
            }

            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandTimeout = 0;
        
                command.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM {table.FullName()} WHERE {timeStampColumn.Name} >= @TIMESTAMP";
                command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter() { ParameterName = "TIMESTAMP", Value = timeStampBeforeInsert, });

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
            
                    while (reader.Read()) //Here the exception is thrown
                    {
                        var entity = new TEntity();

                        foreach (var column in table.Columns)
                        {
                            //Populate entity with values from reader
                        }

                        result.Add(entity);
                    }
                }
            }

            transactionScope.Complete();
            transactionScope.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I have tried the following options in the connectionstring:

```
CommandTimeout = 0;
InternalCommandTimeout = 0;
KeepAlive = 60 * 10;
```

I also have added the `command.CommandTimeOut = 0;` to the command which is used with `ExecuteReader()` to read the data back.

I have further checked the STATEMENT_TIMEOUT of the postgresql server to ensure the server itself has no timeout.

> show STATEMENT_TIMEOUT => "0"

If i do something like `select pg_wait(60 * 10)` on the server i get no error, to the problem must be with my code. What else can i do to track the problem?

Comment: Yes, i have stated that in my question. I have tried CommandTimeout = 0, InternalCommandtimeout = 0 and KeepAlive = 60.

Comment: You may need to increase the `KeepAlive` to a higher value as the connection will be idle during the query.

Comment: @Eldar I have changed the KeepAlive to 600 (should be 10 minutes), but i still get the error after ~ 4 minutes.

Comment: when you run this query  `$"SELECT * FROM {table.FullName()} WHERE {timeStampColumn.Name} >= @TIMESTAMP";`  on the server, how long does it take?

Comment: I use php storm's database plugin to query the database. When i run the query i get the answere in under two seconds. But it is paginated. If i click on "last page" the query runs further and after 31 seconds i get this error: "[2023-09-28 15:42:35] Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is:
[2023-09-28 15:42:35]  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset"

Comment: I have tried it a second time and this time i got a different message: "[2023-09-28 15:44:25] Database client process needs more memory to perform the request.
[2023-09-28 15:44:25] To configure settings, open 'development_db@localhost' data source properties, go to the 'Advanced' tab, and add
[2023-09-28 15:44:25] '-XmxNNNm' to the 'VM options' field, where NNN is the number of megabytes (for example, '-Xmx2048m')." Looks like it needs more memory

Comment: Yeah i have increased the memory and now the exception is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have executed the query which was running when i got the exception and executed it in my php storm's database plugin. After two seconds the result was shown. But it is paginated so i clicked on "to the last page" button. Then after 30 Seconds i got the following error

```
[2023-09-28 15:42:35] Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: 
[2023-09-28 15:42:35] java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

After that i tried it a second time an got another error

```
[2023-09-28 15:44:25] Database client process needs more memory to perform the request. 
[2023-09-28 15:44:25] To configure settings, open 'development_db@localhost' data source properties, go to the 'Advanced' tab, and add 
[2023-09-28 15:44:25] '-XmxNNNm' to the 'VM options' field, where NNN is the number of megabytes (for example, '-Xmx2048m').
```

After increasing the memory to 2048mb as mentioned in the message above, the error is gone.

So the problem was **the server running out of resources** to handle the request. Sadly this error message didn't get raised as an exception for the NpgsqlAdapter.

Comment: What does this answer have to do with C#?

Comment: Nothing. Is that a problem?

Comment: The question was tagged [tag:c#] and describes a problem with a C# function and `SqlClient` I would have thougght the solution needs to be in C# also??

Comment: The problem inside the c# function was caused by an underlying problem of the postgres server. The server ran out of memory and aborted the query, which resulted in the error described in my question. So the solution is to adapt the settings of the server.

Comment: @Olli I have a similar problem in a C# application, where I use the COPY function. I didn't understand exactly which parameter you changed, if it's a parameter of the php storm's database plugin or a server one.
Did you solve also in your C# application? If yes, how?

Comment: "The problem inside the c# function was caused by an underlying problem of the postgres server." Except that Postgresql is not written in Java.  *Something* written in Java is in the chain between C# and the database.  That's why you got the  `java.net.SocketException` error.

Comment: @RonJohn I think that is because i was using php storm's database plugin to execute the querie and php storm is build on IntelliJ IDEA which is written in Java. When php storm got no response it threw the error.